# Exchange the position of two string through bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, debian

I want to exchange the position of two string like `1A to A1`, `2B to B2`

Is that possible in bash?

Now I'm doing it in a stupid way

```
case "$Zone" in
                    1A)
                        Zone="A1"
                        ;;
                    2A)
                        Zone="A2"
                        ;;
                    3A)
                        Zone="A3"
                        ;;
                    4A)
                        Zone="A4"
                        ;;
                    1B)
                        Zone="B1"
                        ;;
                    2B)
                        Zone="B2"
                        ;;
                    3B)
                        Zone="B3"
                        ;;
                    4B)
                        Zone="B4" 
                        ;;
                    E)
                        Zone="E" 
                        ;;
                esac
```

Is there any way smarter?

Comment: Are you always going to have strings with 1-2 characters?

Comment: @fedorqui Yes, always 1-2characters. letter+number or number+letter

Comment: OK, then reversing the string must be enough.

Comment: @fedorqui Yes, I think so. Thank you for helping me twice today.

Comment: No problem, these are interesting questions to handle. Hope you learn from them!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you happen to only have strings with 1 or 2 characters, you can reverse them. And oh, there is the `rev` command in UNIX:

```
zone=$(echo "$zone" | rev)
```

or even shorter

```
zone=$(rev <<< "$zone")
```

See examples:

```
$ zone="E"
$ rev <<< "$zone"
E

$ zone="A1"
$ rev <<< "$zone"
1A
```

From `man rev`:

```
 rev — reverse lines of a file or files
```

Answer (score 3):

your requirement is not clear, what are the possibilities of input? if only `number + A or B` pattern is valid, and needs to be processed?

I assume you need that validation, and this one-liner does that job:

```
awk -v FS=''  '/^[1-5][A-L]$/{$0=$2""$1}7'
```

some examples:

```
kent$  echo "1A
2A
3B
3X
E
foo"|awk -v FS=''  '/^[1-5][A-L]$/{$0=$2""$1}7'
A1
A2
B3
3X
E
foo
```

you see that only if

- the string has length `2`
- and starting with one number in range `[1-5]`
- and ending with `A-L`

it would be get reversed, otherwise, it keeps untouched.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear statement. The possibilities are number(1-5)+(A-L)

Comment: @AvinashRaj those are already explained in document, check gawk manual/man page.

Comment: @Kent Meine Stimme hast du!!

Comment: @jaypal danke! I guess someone was mad at gawk's man page, because it is "so long", and just downvoted my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If reverse a string works then give it a try

```
x=$(echo $zone | rev)
```

Hope it helps:)

Comment: Errr isn't this what I had posted?

Comment: @fedorqui Sorry, I didn't knew that you posted the same, I was in hurry of typing

Comment: Well I posted it 20 minutes before :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the substring expansion to obtain the second and first characters of the string:

```
Zone=${Zone:1:1}${Zone:0:1}
```